# Set up a reverse proxy but links on website showing backend server

Tags: reverse-proxy

So I've just set up an Openlitespeed based reverse proxy, with multiple vhosts pointing to a backend WordPress website. Let's say this WordPress has the link "originalURL".

Now, I have also successfully got a new link working - "newURL".

When I visit http(s)://newURL it shows me the content of originalURL, while retaining newURL in the browser link bar - Great. However, all the hyperlinks on the site are still like https://originalURL/subpage... So when a link is clicked the user gets taken to the original site directly.

How can I fix this?